# Handling large number of MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have an API which is being used by around 200 websites right now. The number is expected to grow very soon. I need to store information of each visitor (IP address etc) on clients' websites. The number of daily visitors for each client ranges from 2000 to 50000. That means I am adding 400000 to 500000 rows everyday. For that right now I am making a different table for each client.

Now the problem is when I try to fetch data from all tables combined, it takes a lot of time. How should I handle this? How should I store the data?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the information you're storing the same for each client. I.e. do the tables have the same structure?

Comment: Make sure you're using correct and minimum sized datatypes, normalize the tables proper to avoid storing duplicate values and only query and extract the exact information nedded

Comment: @mlinth Yes. Structure of the tables is same.

Answer (score 0):

I always try to keep tables to a minimum in my schemas. Perhaps you should make a client table with relevant client information and then have a visitor table with all the visitor information. Link the two with a foreign key.

Comment: In this case, wouldn't the high number of rows affect the performance?

Comment: See the answer by mlinth. SQL databases are pretty good with high row volume, that is the point of the technology.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the tables are the same, I'd just keep the visitor information in one table, with a column to identify the client / website.

The question then is whether a large table like that will still perform... Obviously you need your indexing and so on, but here are a couple of ideas:

[Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html): I know nothing about partitioning on Mysql (but have tried it on Postgresql). The idea is to design the physical data storage to suit your data retrieval / work needs. Might be an idea if your table gets huge.

"Live" and "archive" tables. I'm sure there's proper terminology for this. Again, depending on how you're analysing your data, you can keep today's / this week's / this month's / whatever you need's data in the "live" table where new records are added, then have housekeeping functions that move older records to a larger archive table. The idea would be to keep only the records you want to analysis frequently in the smaller live table, so query performance is fast.

Lastly, you might be pleasantly surprised by the performance of Mysql even on large tables. I've got a Postgresql table with several million records and performance is more than adequate without any playing around.

Comment: So when I need to see the total numbers (total visitors of all clients combined) then that will be just like fetching data from a single table where I stored all the data, right? Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's how it would work. Oh, and if you're only interested in total hits, you could create a table "totalhits" with one integer field, and increment that number with the number of added records to the main table - you could do that through php or with a trigger...

Comment: Okay. I will definitely try this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do not store raw data in mysql. Put visitors data into queue (based on redis, rabbitmq etc) and store only aggregated data which is necessary for your business model.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of redis etc. I will have to look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.